# Issues sending a POST via Net::HTTP to a Battle.Net Community API End-Point (OAuth 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, oauth-2.0, omniauth

**Versions:**

- Ruby 2.2.4
- Rails 4.2
- Omniauth-oauth2 1.3.1
- Omniauth-bnet 1.1.0

**Issue:**

Trying to complete the authorization and token request process to Blizzard's Battle Net Community API.  While I can get the authorization_code returned, when I attempt to construct a POST back to the token endpoint it keeps telling me that its an invalid request/internal server error or just returns back the following object:  `<Net::HTTPFound 302 Found readbody=true>` which has a blank string for a response body.  Details for how Blizzard recommends handling the OAuth 2 process are located here:  [Battle.net OAuth 2 Guide](https://dev.battle.net/docs/read/oauth).  The omniauth-bnet gem is the one Blizzard suggested but doesn't seem to handle the entire OAuth authorization and token process but I'll freely admit I'm brand new when it comes to anything OAuth related so I could be wrong.

Any help you all can provide would be very welcome!

**Controller Code:**

```
def index
  client_id = ENV[BNET_CLIENT_ID]
  client_secret = ENV[BNECT_CLIENT_SECRET]
  uri = URI('https://us.battle.net/auth/token?
  redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2f127%2f0%2f0%2f1%3A3001%2Fauth%2Fbnet%2Fcallback
    &grant_type=authorization_code
    &code=' + params["code"])
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
  req.basic_auth(client_id, client_secret)
  res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: uri.scheme == 'https') {|http| http.request(req)}
  @bnet_response = res.body
end
```

**Process:**

- Click link on index.html page which triggers the authorization process to start by sending a GET request to https://us.battle.net/oauth/authorize?client_id=&client_secret=&redirect_uri=&response_type=code
- BNet API accepts the request and redirects user to Battle.Net Login screen
- User authorizes app and is redirected (via redirect_uri) back to the index page with query parameters for the authorization_code
- My app SHOULD make a POST request using the controller code above and the response should contain the actual access token.

This is just some hastily cobbled together code while I'm trying to get this working.  I'll clean it up once I get over this little speed bump.  I wouldn't hardcode the URI and such normally, just getting frustrated with things.

**Things I've tried:**

- Using Rest-Client : There's a callback redirect that it can't handle apparently
- Testing Postman : When using their OAuth 2 Authorization it works just fine, also works fine if I use Postman to get the authorization code (GET) and token (POST), so I'm assuming things work on the Blizz side and my code just sucks.

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#index'
  get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'pages#index'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Battle.net API, however reading your process it seems you are getting an authorization code back from the redirect in the form of a query parameter (accessed by `params[:code]`) correct?

You also mention that this works using Postman indicating the flaw must be somewhere in the code.

I would suggest using the following snippet and let me know if it works. I would encourage using `puts url` after `url = ...` code to ensure the URI looks exactly as you want it (and has the correct code, client id, secret, redirect_uri).

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

# Remember to change the redirect uri to match yours
redirect_uri = 'https://my-domain-name.com/auth/bnet/callback'

# Double check the environment variable names for BNET ID / Secret
url = URI("https://us.battle.net/oauth/token?redirect_uri=#{redirect_uri}&code=#{params[:code]}" \
          "&grant_type=authorization_code&scope=wow.profile&client_id=#{ENV['BNET_CLIENT_ID']}" \
          "&client_secret=#{ENV['BNET_CLIENT_SECRET']}")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)

response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

Ensure your domain is accessible over **https** as this seems to be required.